# What is basic structure of xml for importing a page in wordpress?

Tags: import

I am trying to import file from xml to word press i need to know waht is sturcture for importing the xml file into a page in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a full load of Importer Plugins that you can install from the `~/wp-admin/tools/import` screen. They will serve as nice reference.

Then there's [Ralf Alberts @Ralf912 Importer skeleton](https://gist.github.com/RalfAlbert/4743800) on GitHub/Gist which you can take as reference. Please note that this skeleton uses namespaces and therefore requires PHP 5.3+, or a rewrite.

The main/important parts are the following:

1. Check if the request comes from `admin.php?import=...`

   ```
   if ( ! defined( 'WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS' ) )
       return;
   ```
2. Load Importer API (Importer API = Backendpage `admin.php?import=...`)

   ```
   require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/import.php';
   ```
3. Load the importer base class

   ```
   if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_Importer' ) ) {
       $class_wp_importer = ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php';
       if ( file_exists( $class_wp_importer ) )
           require $class_wp_importer;
   }
   ```
4. Register your Custom Importer to WordPress by using [`register_importer()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_importer/) - [Codex explanation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_importer)

   ```
   register_importer(
       'custom',
       'CustomPress',
       __('Import <strong>posts</strong> or not.', 'custom-importer'),
       array(
           new Custom_Import(),
           'dispatch'
           )
   );
   ```

Comment: really i m extremely new to wordpress but i know some basics, i really need to know is there is any way to import file from indesign to Wordpress if u can help me on this is will be great help..thanx in advance

Comment: @user2290642 First: Please try to use proper English, full sentences and upper-/lowercase characters. This is no chat. Second: This is _no_ "do this job for me for free"-channel. The site works more in in the way of "You ask by showing what you tried and where you're stuck and get guidance in return".